# Automate a browser application

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser, automation, ui-automation

Does any one know is there any automation tool to automate a browser application? We have developed new browser application.

While googled I had seen lots of GUI automation testing tools and most of them are related to either web application or windows application.

Currently I don't want to test any web application only need to automate the functionalities of that browser application like (presence of tool bar, menu bar, preferences etc etc).

I googled and seen lots of GUI automation tools. But I'm not sure  which one I have to select.

http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/best-gui-testing-tools/

Please some one suggest a good tool to do browser app automation testing(not web application).

Comment: Do you want to test the presence of tool bar, menu bar, preferences of a particular browser?